# h5py returning unexpected results in indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

I'm attempting to fill an h5py dataset with a series of numpy arrays that I generate in sequence so my memory can handle it.

The h5py array is initialised so that the first dimension can have any magnitude,

```
f.create_dataset('x-data', (1, maxlen, 50), maxshape=(None, maxlen, 50))
```

After generating each numpy array X, I am using

```
f['x-data'][alen:alen + len(data),:,:] = X
```

Where for example, in the first array, alen=0 and len(data)=10056. I then increment alen so the next array will start from where the last one ended.

```
print f['x-data'][alen:alen + len(data),:,:].shape, alen, len(data)

(1L, 60L, 50L) 0 10056
```

Does anyone know why the 0:10056 indexing is being interpreted as 1L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from a helpful person on the user group.

The maxshape(None) feature does not mean that the dataset automatically resizes - it must be resized each time new input is added. So the first dimension must be increased before adding new data:

```
    x.resize((x.shape[0] + X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
    y.resize((y.shape[0] + Y.shape[0], Y.shape[1], Y.shape[2]))
```

The dataset then adds the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your example, but on a much smaller scale.  I had to do a resize each time I added elements, e.g.

```
f['xdata'].resize(50,axis=0)
```

The first time I tried to add a block I got an error:

```
TypeError: Can't broadcast (10, 20, 10) -> (1, 20, 10)
```

But subsequent times, when I'd outgrown the allocated space, it failed silently.  No error, it just didn't end up storing the new values.

This is for version 2.2.1

Comment: See my answer, I found the solution. The maxshape(None) feature doesn't resize the dataset automatically - would be nice if it did though.