# Appending a new row of data to an existing .mat file in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mat

I couldn't see a good explanation on the internet, which explains how to append a new row of data to an existing .mat file in python.

I have checked this link; [How to append in .mat file row or columnwise cellmatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082884/how-to-append-in-mat-file-row-or-columnwise-cellmatrix), but it didn't help.

How can I manage appending in python for .mat file?

Thanks,

Comment: The `scipy` `savemat` function takes an openned file.  So it might be possible to open the file in append mode (flag 'a'), and pass it to `savemat`.  But at most I expect you will be able add a variable to the file, not values to an existing array.

Comment: I tried appending to an existing `.mat` and messed up the header; you'll probably have to load the data from the existing file. create new arrays as needed, and save a fresh file.

Comment: hpaulj, the problem is, I will create a very large data like 5 columns and 3237 rows. Before trying this issue, I was creating a numpy array, and then saving that as a mat file. But when it comes to 1656th data, it used to give "Killed" error. That's why, I need to append value to the end of the mat file, and delete the appended value from the cache.

Comment: `h5py` lets you extend arrays.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32262870/901925

Comment: An earlier SO on appending to a .mat: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29042033/901925.  With some constraints I was able (in March) to append a new variable to an existing .mat.